# Unable to turn bluetooth on

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

I upgraded my system to ubuntu 17.10. I could turn on my bluetooth and use it normally. But today, I don't know why and how, I can't turn it on. In the top-right I can only press **Turn Off** open **Bluetooth Settings**. The **Turn Off** button doesn't toggle even if I press it. Even when I open the Bluetooth Settings I can't turn it on from there.

Does anybody have a solution?

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2(settings)]

Comment: I know a  little French (thanks to the ex-wife)... "Pas" signals a negative and "trouvé" is a form of the verb "to find" so, is it saying "not found" or something? If so, it can be hardware. If it happened suddenly it probably is.

Comment: Is there a hardware switch on your computer to turn off Bluetooth and/or other RF activity? You might have accidentally switched it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem today, and found out the problem was related to `rfkill`. So I tried

```
$ rfkill list 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes   <-- ah ah!
    Hard blocked: no
(...)
```

The command `rfkill unblock 0` did the trick.

That being said, I have no idea why all of a sudden I ended up in that state... (or why the UI is not able to detect/fix that problem on its own).

Comment: I had the same problem, but for me this solution doesn't work because I have neither soft or hard block in rfkill. The only solution I found was restarting my computer.